# "Source file corrupted: SHA-1 hash mismatch" error from Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, data-integrity

While installing an application on Windows 2008, I get the below problem in the middle of installation:

> Source file corrupted: SHA-1 hash mismatch.

Here's the section of the log file.

```
2013-01-28 21:55:36.945   Installing the file.
2013-01-28 21:55:37.397   Source file corrupted: SHA-1 hash mismatch.
2013-01-28 21:55:37.881   Defaulting to Abort for suppressed message box 
                          (Abort/Retry/Ignore):
                          C:\Program Files (x86)\XYZ\XY.exe
                          
                          An error occurred while trying to copy a file:
                          The source file is corrupted.
                          
                          Click Retry to try again, Ignore to skip this 
                          file (not recommended), or Abort to cancel 
                           installation.
2013-01-28 21:55:37.881   User canceled the installation process.
2013-01-28 21:55:37.881   Rolling back changes.
```

Can someone help to resolve the issue?

The installer as produced by Inno Setup compiler is valid and working. The corruption happened somewhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question: [Integrity check of whole Inno Setup installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70169994/850848)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error indicates, the installer has been corrupted somehow.  This is most likely due to a bad download.  Have the user download the installer again.  (Note however that the problem may still happen, either due to a repeat of whatever caused the original download failure, or due to something caching the bad file.)